# Invariance signature in infinite dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces, gm.general-mathematics, general-relativity, inner-product

Let $V$ be an infinite dimensional vector space and suppose we have a smooth family $\{g_t\}_{t\ge 0}$ of symmetric bi-linear forms such that:

1. $g_0$ is positive-definite
2. $g_t$ is non-degenerate for all $t\ge 0$

Is it true that $g_t$ is positive-definite for all $t\ge 0$? Clearly this is true when $V$ is of finite dimension.

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by “smooth”? If you're merely demanding that for all $x,y\in V$ the function $t \mapsto g_t(x,y)$ is a smooth (e.g., $C^\infty$) with no uniformity assumption, I suspect this doesn't suffice, but something stronger might.

Comment: Let $V=C[0,1]$ and $g_t(f,g)=\int_0^1(x-t)f(x)g(x)dx$. Would this count as a "smooth" family in your sense?

Comment: @Wojowu The savvy reader will know which $g$ is what when reading your comment. 